# MVC4 popup message to user machine without client running

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to send and show a popup message to user no matter whether client application is running on that machine or not?

To be more specific, I have a module where user can request to perform an operation to another user. An email is being sent to the target user, however I want to show a popup message to user that he got a request for new assignment. Is it possible to achieve this? If yes then could someone explain to it me how? I am using MVC4 Intranet application.

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no such platform independent technology yet, but some web browsers already support something that could help - [serviceWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API).

> Service workers essentially act as proxy servers that sit between web
>   applications, and the browser and network (when available.) They are
>   intended to (amongst other things) enable the creation of effective
>   offline experiences, intercepting network requests and taking
>   appropriate action based on whether the network is available and
>   updated assets reside on the server. They will also allow access to
>   push notifications and background sync APIs.

If you a Facebook user, you might be noticed that Facebook web site could push you some updates to some browsers like latest Chrome event when web site itself is not loaded. So it could help, but has two catch:

1. Client browser should support Service Workers
2. Browser should run on client machine to be able to show push message.

A detailed guide from Google could found [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/?hl=en).

Comment: well explained. Thank you